# Connection between rank and matrix product

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I have a problem understanding the following:

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and let t $\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that
>   $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq t$ if and only if there exists an $m \times t$ matrix $B$ and a $t \times n$ matrix $C$ so that $A = BC$.

I know what a rank is but I can't make a connection between the rank and the existence of two matrices such that $A = BC$.

Comment: Does the term "singular value decomposition" mean something to you? If the connection between an SVD and the rank is clear, the above statement is easy to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Think of matrices as linear transformations: $A:F^n\to F^m$, $C:F^n\to F^t$, $B:F^t\to F^m$. If $\mathrm{rk}(A)\le t$, then $\mathrm{Im}(A)\le t$, so there exists a $t$-dimensional subspace $T$ of $F^m$, such that $\mathrm{Im}(A)\subset T$. Consequently, if we restrict $A$ to $A'=C:F^n\to T$, and let $B:T\to F^m$ be the canonical inclusion, we have $A=BC$. The converse is obvious: If $A=BC$, then
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{rk}(A)=\mathrm{rk}(BC)\le\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Im}(B))\le t,
\end{equation}
because the domain of $B$ is $t$-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Theorem that states that 
Rank(XY)<=min(rankX, rankY)
So 
Rank(BC)<=min(rankB, rankC)
So if t is less than n and m. Then it could be the rank of either B or C 
Rank(BC)<=t. 
I hope this helps.